# Using $ORIGIN with setuid application does not fail as expected

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, clang++, setuid

I have a `librandom.so` library and a `main` exectuable which was compiled as follows:

```
$ clang++ -o main main.o -lrandom -L. -Wl,-rpath,"\$ORIGIN"
```

They are both in the same directory. Since `main` has `$ORIGIN` in its `rpath`, it works fine - `./main` returns without errors.

Now, I'm setting `main` to run with `setuid` as `root`:

```
$ sudo chown root main
$ sudo chmod a+s main
$ ./main
```

I expected `main` to fail since `$ORIGIN` is not expanded in `setuid` applications. Surprisingly, it works.

If I run `main` from another directory, though, it *does* fail as expected:

```
$ cd /tmp    
$ /path/to/main
/path/to/main: error while loading shared libraries: librandom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why does it work when I run `main` from its containing directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I expected main to fail since $ORIGIN is not expanded in setuid applications.
> Surprisingly, it works.

Glibc has a long history of expanding `$ORIGIN` even for suid binaries (see e.g. [CVE-2010-3847](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2010/Oct/257)). The motivation behind this is that suid binaries that use `$ORIGIN` for rpath are broken by design so Glibc developers were never very bothered to fix this. Some downstream distros provided patches on top of stock Glibc which disable ORIGIN-expansion so exact situation depends on your distro.

Funny enough, only free-standing `$ORIGIN` will be expanded - if you replace it with e.g. `$ORIGIN/libs` it'll start to fail.

> Why does it work when I run main from its containing directory?

Once you move your file, `$ORIGIN` will expand to different folder which no longer contains the required library.

Comment: Regarding the second parts - I'm not moving the file, just the current directory. `$ORIGIN` is relative to the location of the executable, not the current working directory.

Comment: Right. It seems Ubuntu uses variant of Glibc patch that expands `$ORIGIN` to empty string (e.g. described in [this comment](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12393#c0)). Dynamic linker will then treat this as CWD which would explain the behavior. You can probably [report this to developers](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/) but I doubt they'll be interested.